# Cronjob - Running Scripts and Python

Tags: python, cron

My problem is that the cronjob seems to be running fine, but not executing the code properly within the .sh files, please see below for details.

I type crontab -e, to bring up cron:
In that file:

```
30 08 * * 1-5 /home/user/path/backup.sh
45 08 * * 1-5 /home/user/path/runscript.sh >> /home/user/cronlog.log 2>&1
```

backup.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -e "NEW_BACKUP.sql.gz" ]
then
    mv "NEW_BACKUP.sql.gz" "OLD_BACKUP.sql.gz"
fi
mysqldump -u username -ppassword db --max_allowed_packet=99M | gzip -9c > NEW_BACKUP.sql.gz
```

runscript.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
python /home/user/path/uber_sync.py
```

uber_sync.py:

```
import keyword_sync
import target_milestone_sync
print "Starting Sync"
keyword_sync.sync()
print "Keyword Synced"
target_milestone_sync.sync()
print "Milestone Synced"
print "Finished Sync"
```

The problem is, it seems to do the print statements in uber_sync, but not actually execute the code from the import statements... Any ideas?

Also note that keyword_sync and target_milestone_sync are located in the same directory as uber_sync, namely /home/user/path

Thank you for any help.

Comment: so, what's ending up in `/home/user/cronlog.log`? any stacktrace? - oh, and without knowing what the `sync()`s do it will be hard to tell what could be going wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your import statements fail because python can not locate your modules. Add them them to your search path and then import your modules, like this (add this to uber_sync.py):

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/user/path")
import keyword_sync
import target_milestone_sync
```

Python looks for modules in the current directory (the dir the code is executed in), in the `$PYTHONPATH` environment variable and config files. This all ends up in `sys.path` which can be edited like any list object. If you want to learn more about the reasons a certain module gets imported or not i suggest also looking into the standard module [imp](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html).

In your case you tested your code in `/home/user/path` via `python uber_sync.py` and it worked, because your modules were in the current directory. But when execute it in `some/other/dir` via `python /home/user/path/uber_sync.py` the current dir becomes `some/other/dir` and your modules are not found.

Comment: I will run the cron again tonight and see if this fixes it, it is what I suspected to be the problem so hopefully this works! Thank you

Comment: Another note: I also had to change the backup script to absolute paths as well.